# Итоговый запрос

Tags: oracle, sql

Пожалуйста, помогите с запросом. Мне нужно по отделениям вывести максимальную и минимальную зарплату, а также фио тех, кто получает эту зарплату. Вот пример того, как я нахожу просто указанные зарплаты, а вот что делать с фио...

```
select bno,min(salary),max(salary)
from o_staff
group by bno
order by bno;
```

(bno)-код отдела

Comment: И что должно получиться из:?

    fio | salary  | bno
    A   | 1000    | 1
    B   | 1000    | 1
    C   | 500     | 1
    D   | 100     | 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.bno, 
       q1.maxSalary, 
       q2.minSalary , 
       t1.salary, 
       t1.fio 
from   staff t1, 
       (select max(salary) as maxSalary, bno from staff group by bno) q1,
       (select min(salary) as minSalary, bno from staff group by bno) q2
where  (q1.maxSalary=t1.salary and t1.bno=q1.bno and t1.bno=q2.bno) 
or     (t1.bno = q2.bno and q2.minSalary=t1.salary and t1.bno=q1.bno)
order  by t1.bno;
```

Comment: @Ilmirus. Проверьте, пожалуйста, мой запрос в новой редакции

Comment: Большое спасибо , работает!)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, Вам надо вывести фио сотрудников, получающих в отделениях максимальную или минимальную зарплату:

```
select fio, 
       salary, 
       bno 
from   table1 t
where  salary = (select min(salary) from table1 where bno = t.bno) 
or     salary = (select max(salary) from table1 where bno = t.bno);
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю - такое не работает) [ (a) in (a,b) ]

Comment: Не понял, что не работает? 

a in (select...)не работает?

Comment: in работает если слева и справа одностолбцовые выражения... Вроде...

Comment: Не работает: ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"